# Custom action using custom command class and dialog in magnolia

Tags: magnolia

I would like to have a custom action on the pages app that opens up a dialog with one field for a comment and two actions, namely `cancel` and `commit`. The commit action calls the custom ExportToGitCommand class.

I defined a custom action definition and class action for the pages app in magnolia:

```
public class ExportToGitCommandAction extends AbstractCommandAction<ExportToGitCommandActionDefinition>{

    public ExportToGitCommandAction(ExportToGitCommandActionDefinition definition, JcrItemAdapter item,
            CommandsManager commandsManager, UiContext uiContext, SimpleTranslator i18n) {
        super(definition, item, commandsManager, uiContext, i18n);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public ExportToGitCommandAction(ExportToGitCommandActionDefinition definition, List<JcrItemAdapter> items,
            CommandsManager commandsManager, UiContext uiContext, SimpleTranslator i18n) {
        super(definition, items, commandsManager, uiContext, i18n);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

In the Config app I defined myAction:

```
MyAction
      class ->ch.xxx.module.versioning.ExportToGitCommandActionDefinition
      command -> /modules/xxx-module-versioning/commands/versioning/gitexport
      dialogName -> /modules/xxx-module-versioning/dialogs/saveversion
```

The constructor in `ExportToGitCommandAction`gets invoked but the dialog and command from `myAction` are not. What methods do I need to implement so that the `myAction`:

1. opens a dialog
2. executes the custom command

The custom command `gitexport` code is:

```
public class ExportToGitCommand extends BaseRepositoryCommand {

  @Override
  public boolean execute(Context context) throws Exception {
  //custom code here
}
}
```

**Part of the solution**

Under the pages app I created an action using the following configuration:

```
MyAction
     class ->i nfo.magnolia.ui.framework.action.OpenCreateDialogActionDefinition
     dialogName -> xxx-module-versioning:gitexport
     icon -> icon-i-beacon
     label -> MyAction
```

Under the xxx-module-versioning app I configured the dialog:

```
xxx-module-versioning
   commands
   dialogs
      gitexport 
         form
         actions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution that worked.
In the magnolia pages app in magnolia configuration configure a custom action:
[image]

In the respective module defined under dialogName define the dialog:
[image]

The custom class extends `CommandActionDefinition`:

```
public class ExportToGitCommandActionDefinition extends CommandActionDefinition{

    public ExportToGitCommandActionDefinition() {
        this.setImplementationClass(ExportToGitCommandAction.class);    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made an error in definition of your action. You need to specify "name" of the command in your catalog, not path to it. And you need to specify catalog name if it is different from "default".

Try this:

```
MyAction
  class ->ch.xxx.module.versioning.ExportToGitCommandActionDefinition
  command -> gitexport
  catalog -> versioning
  dialogName -> /modules/xxx-module-versioning/dialogs/saveversion
```

Comment: Hi @Jan. Thanks for your response but this unfortunately doesn't work. What I like to achieve is that the custom action on the pages app opens up a dialog with one field for a comment and two action, namely cancel and commit. The commit action calls the custom ExportToGitCommand class. What is the recommended way to implement this?